# Change the color of an empty or 0 cell in html table

Tags: html, css

I have a html table that displays mysql data.
How to change the color of an empty or =0 cell ?
THX.

```html
<table border="1px" align="center">
 <tr><td><?php echo $data['value1'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $data['value2'] ?></td></tr>
  </table>
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; background-color: white; padding: 1px; text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;}
```

Comment: The color or the background-color?

Comment: @MadalinaTaina It can't have a `color` if it's empty...there would be no text to affect.

Comment: Add a default style for cells if you intend to customize then just the content of the cells.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's the point... It seems too simple to set the background...

Comment: @Paulie_D And I learned to ask for more info here from you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add logic when rendering your result to provide a way to style it. I recommend adding a class to the cell. In this example I'm using a function to determine what to render but you can solve this any way you please.

```
<?php
  function renderCell($value){
    if(is_null($value) || (is_numeric($value) && $value == 0) || $value == ''){
      return '<td class="zero">'.$value.'</td>';
    } else {
      return '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
  }
?>
<table border="1px" align="center">
  <tr>
    <?php echo(renderCell($data['value1'])); ?>
    <?php echo(renderCell($data['value2'])); ?>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
  }
  td{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    background-color:white;
    padding:1px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:8pt;
  }
  td.zero{
    /* style "zero" values differently */
    background-color:#fac;
    color:#f00;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thx a lot, is very helpful.

Comment: It works but it add another empty cell before mine. How can solve this?  THX.

Comment: It should only render 1 cell for each time it is called.  However if the value is blank (e.g. An empty string or null it will render an empty cell.) is there a different behaviour you want for blank value Since?

Comment: I understood, but i don't want to add a cell each time it's called, just to change it in a different color or border color  if it's empty or value=0. Because i have more than 10 cells with a table head, and it don't coincide thead with values of columns. THX.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit lost for what you're after. If you just want a text color you could wrap the value in a span instead.... And output that in a td/th/whatever.

Comment: So i have to change in the function td with span? Sorry, i'm new in programmation and i don't know too much how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:empty` pseudo

```css
td:empty {background: green;}
table {table-layout: fixed;}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it works for empty cells, but how to do for values =0 ? THX.

Comment: Is value=0 the content of the cell?

Comment: yes, because when i don't complete an input when i pass values into database, it takes 0 by default for number type.

Comment: Then you will need logic as scunliffe has explained below.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `:empty` pseudo class like

**CSS**

```
td:empty {
 background:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1px" align="center">
    <tr><td><?php echo $data['value1'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['value2'] ?></td></tr>
  </table>
```